# Warning: When only one parameter is given, it must be an array

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select minimum and maximum value for capacity from MySQL table but whenever I try I get the following error:

> Warning: min(): When only one parameter is given, it must be an array
>   in /campus/campus.php on line 38 Call Stack: 0.0003 352296 1. {main}()
>   /campus/campus.php:0 0.0124 1654304 2. min() /campus/campus.php:38
>   Warning: max(): When only one parameter is given, it must be an array
>   in /campus/campus.php on line 39 Call Stack: 0.0003 352296 1. {main}()
>   /campus/campus.php:0 0.0125 1654360 2. max() /campus/campus.php:39

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$sql= "SELECT MIN(capacity), MAX(capacity) FROM room";

$res =& $db->query($sql);
if (PEAR::isError($res)) {
    die($res->getMessage());
}

while($row = $res->fetchRow())
    {
        $minCapacity = $row[MIN(capacity)];
        $maxCapacity = $row[MAX(capacity)];
    }

echo $minCapacity;
echo $maxCapacity;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $minCapacity = $row['MIN(capacity)'];
                        ^--           ^--
```

the indicated quotes are missing. `min()` is a valid PHP function, so you're trying to use the results of PHP's min function as an array index in $row.

Comment: There is nothing being returned from the table and the variables $minCapacity and $maxCapacity are 0.

Comment: Then do a `var_dump($row)` and see what you're getting from the fetch call.

Comment: Just figured it out. Works perfectly now. Fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try assigning an alias to your MIN and MAX like this:

```
$sql= "SELECT MIN(capacity) AS myMIN, MAX(capacity) AS myMAX FROM room";
```

Then in your code do the following:

```
while($row = $res->fetchRow())
    {
        $minCapacity = $row['myMIN'];
        $maxCapacity = $row['myMAX'];
    }
```

Just a thought.

Comment: The $minCapacity and $maxCapacity seem to be both 0.

Answer (score 1):

Create an alias for your query: Select min(capacity) as minVal. This makes it possible to extract the value from your array.

Answer (score 0):

MIN(capacity) and MAX(capacity) should be in quotes in your while loop.

You are trying to call the php functions max and min (which require an array if only one param is given) rather than reference the results of your sql query.

Answer (score 0):

MIN and MAX are interpreted as PHP functions by the parser. Try enclosing them in quotation marks to present them as a key for the map in $row (assuming they are represented as such in the query result).